# How to excute a method from other class

Tags: c#

I am doing a shop management project.
When I sell a product, the balance is not updating in main from.
I'm doing like this:

method in main from:

```
public partial class admin : Form
{

    public void update_balance()
    {
        var con = new MySqlConnection(sql);
        con.Open();
        var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT total FROM balance", con);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            balance.Text = reader.GetString(0);
        }
    }
}
```

now calling this method from buy/sell from

```
admin a1 = new admin();
a1.update_balance();
```

but balance is not updating in main from.

Comment: You are updating balance for a new admin form not the original instance form.

Comment: show the admin form code as well. But only the relevant part

Comment: well i am just  calling update_balance() in admin from.

Comment: how can i update in original instance form ???

Comment: @LonelyTanvir: you need to access the opened form using `Application.OpenForms[]` , see my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem1 :** you are trying to get the decimal type as String using `GetString()`

**Solution :** use `GetDecimal()` to get the total and then convert it into String.

Try This:

```
 balance.Text = reader.GetDecimal(0).ToString();
```

**or**

you can use `Index` directly `reader[Index]` and convert using `ToString()`

```
 balance.Text = reader[0].ToString();
```

**Problem 2:**
You are creating new instance variable form admin form and updating the balance.

**Solution 2:** you can not assign the value by newly created instance variable. you need to use `Application.OpenForms[FormName]` method to get the Already opened adminform to update admin form.

**Complete Code:**

```
public partial class admin : Form
{

  public void update_balance()
  {
    var con = new MySqlConnection(sql);
    con.Open();
    var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT total FROM balance", con);
    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        balance.Text = reader[0].ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Use following code From buy/Sell Form

```
        admin adminform= (admin) Application.OpenForms["admin"]; //your formname  i assume it is admin
        adminform.updateform();
```